# Turning column of year data into time series in Excel

Tags: excel, date, time

I've got some publicly available data that I'd like to plot as a time series.

However, when I try to plot it, it plots two lines. It appears that Excel can't work out that the Year column is time. How do I convert it?

```
Year    Area planted    Area harvested   Yield  Production
1909    29,196          27,018           15.5   417,796
1910    32,878          28,152           15.3   429,875
1911    33,653          29,780           14.4   428,740
1912    35,709          28,406           14.2   402,703
```

This is the output

[image: This is the output from the chart]

Comment: What kind of chart did you use?

Comment: you should first convert the observations of column Year as a Date, otherwise excel will consider it as any other variable.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I used a 2D line

Comment: @MamounBenghezal I tried to set the type using the Custom format, but that didn't work.

Comment: @elksie5000 I just converted it as  01/01/1909 and it works fine for me.
Without a custom format it seems OK.
Make sure your date is aligned on the right and not the left of cells for text.

Comment: @MamounBenghezal The problem I have is that all the years come out as 1905

Comment: You can't just change the format.  You have to convert the value into a "real date".

Comment: You'll need to re-enter the values (or use a derived column, e.g. `DATEVALUE(A1&"-01-01")`), otherwise Excel will just reinterpret the value `1909` as a numeric date/time offset (which will end up as somewhere in 1905).

Comment: @elksie5000 if you convert it direcly as date the year will be 1905, it normal. But before conversion, try `Concat("1/1/", 1909)`,  etc, then you convert your data with the appropriate format.

Comment: Also, with the wide range of values that you have, you will probably need to either scale those values, or use some combination of a logarithmic y axis and a secondary axis in order to visualize the plots.

Comment: @MamounBenghezal Thank you to both of you. It now works.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you for your help. I was going to do a series of plots, but couldn't work out the date format thing.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your year to a date, and then convert the date to a year.

The formula is:  YEAR(DATE(A2,1,1))